# Error: Let's Encrypt nonce request status на VestaCP

Tags: debian, letsencrypt, vesta

ОС Debian

```
v-add-letsencrypt-domain user domain.ru
Error: Let's Encrypt nonce request status
```

Нашел [такое решение](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=19158&sid=546e4578c6bfabaff6dfcba4bef1926b&start=10#p85142)

```
tail -f /var/log/vesta/letsencrypt.log
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : --- Requesting nonce / STEP 1 ---
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : curl -s -I "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : answer=
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : nonce=
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : status=
[Tue Nov 9 12:37:04 UTC 2021] : EXIT=Let's Encrypt nonce request status

Solved: apt-get install curl
```

Но когда пробую переустановить curl, получается следующее

```
apt install curl  -y --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/202 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 58165 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.38.0-4+deb8u16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u16) over (7.38.0-4+deb8u16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up atop (1.26-2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K013proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'nglnx' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script '3proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rmnologin if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 5
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall if started
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mdadm-raid at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service dovecot at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 7
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package atop (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up vesta-nginx (0.9.8-21) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K013proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'nglnx' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script '3proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rmnologin if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 5
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall if started
insserv: There is a loop between service 3proxy and mountall-bootclean if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mdadm-raid at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service dovecot at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 7
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting 3proxy depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package vesta-nginx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atop
 vesta-nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Что делать? Спасибо.

Comment: Ты пытаешься установить сертификат Let's Encrypt для домена?

Comment: Да, это правда.

Comment: так зачем использовать какие-то костыли, которые не работают, если есть официальная инструкция установки сертификата через `snap` Вот ссылка https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=debian-10 выбери там необходимый web-сервер и ОС, а далее по всё по инструкции

Answer (score 0):

Установка сертификата `Let's Encrypt` с помощью `certbot`, через `snap` на примере web-сервера `nginx` и OS Debian:

1. Подключаешься к серверу по SSH.
2. Устанавливаешь `snapd`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade -y ; \
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

3. Выполняешь следующие команды, чтобы убедиться, что установлена последняя версия `snapd`:

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
```

4. Если ранее были установлены какие-либо пакеты `certbot` с помощью диспетчера пакетов `apt`, надо удалить их перед установкой привязки c `certbot`, либо можно пропустить этот шаг, если установка `certbot` не осуществлялась через установщик пакетов:

```
sudo apt-get remove certbot
```

5. Теперь устанавливаешь `certbot`:

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

6. Выполняешь следующую инструкцию в командной строке, чтобы убедиться, что команда `certbot` может быть запущена:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

7. Запускаешь команду ниже, чтобы `certbot` выдал сертификат и автоматически настроил конфигурацию `nginx` для его обслуживания, включив доступ HTTPS за один шаг:

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

При настройке надо будет расшарить свой email и выбрать, чтобы `certbot` автоматически перенаправлял все запросы с `http` на `https`. Ну вот и всё. Теперь просто перейди на свой сайт и убедись, что браузере появился значок замка в строке URL-адреса.